# Pass JSON from SQL Server to D3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, d3.js

I'm building an ASP.NET using C#, Visual Studio, SQL Server, D3.JS.
I have values in a SQL Server that I'm getting from the database and the results are:

```
    [
     {"AMOUNT":1.000000000000000e+002},{"AMOUNT":1.000000000000000e+003},
     {"AMOUNT":1.000000000000000e+004},{"AMOUNT":5.000000000000000e+003}, {"AMOUNT":2.000000000000000e+003},{"AMOUNT":1.000000000000000e+003},
     {"AMOUNT":5.000000000000000e+003},{"AMOUNT":3.000000000000000e+003},{"AMOUNT":8.000000000000000e+003},{"AMOUNT":1.200000000000000e+004},
     {"AMOUNT":5.000000000000000e+003},{"AMOUNT":1.300000000000000e+004},
     {"AMOUNT":1.500000000000000e+004}
    ]
```

Okay so my Json output is correct, below is code I'm using to get the json output above:

```
  public string jsonString = "";
      public string JasonGet()
        {
            var queryWithForJson = "SELECT  AMOUNT FROM PeopleTable WHERE Bal = 'Acc' FOR JSON AUTO";
            var conn = new SqlConnection(@"MyConnectSource!");
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryWithForJson, conn);
            conn.Open();
            var jsonResult = new StringBuilder();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (!reader.HasRows)
            {
                jsonResult.Append("[]");
            }
            else
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    jsonResult.Append(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                }
            }
            Label1.Text = jsonResult.ToString();
           // jsonString = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(jsonResult);
            return (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(jsonResult);
        }
```

And this works fine above I believe since I am putting the results on a label1.Text from a jsonString to see it for myself but the last return line is where I'm part confused because now I wish to pass the JSON result to my D3.JS. Let me show what I'm doing in D3...

```
        <script>  
            d3.json('<%= JasonGet() %>').then(function (data) {
            console.log("Json string: " + data);
             });
</script>
```

Okay so I believe in my C# function that I have the correct results but I think the error is when I'm passing the values to my Javascript. Below is the error code I'm getting:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

and

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

I appreciate any suggestions, sorry if it's not explained properly but to sum it up, we are getting json values from the database from a C# function and then want to pass it into Javascript.

Comment: Do some debugging - what is the json string that is being returned to the client? Is it valid json?

Comment: d3.json expects the first argument to be a URL where it go to fetch some JSON (via AJAX), not the actual JSON string itself. If you're going to inject the values directly into the JavaScript like that, then clearly you don't need an asynchronous function to go and fetch it....you'd just be able to log it to the console immediately :-)

Comment: You can just do `var data = <%= JasonGet() %>;`